# CheckedListBox and list of checked items with their indexes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` like this:

```
:'''''''''''''''/\
: [ ] item1     ||
: [x] item2     ||
: [ ] item3     ##
: [ ] item4     ||
: [x] item5     ||
L...............\/
```

Now I want to extract indexes of checked items:

```
int[] indexes = ExtractCheckedIndexes (myCheckedListBox);
```

Now indexes should have 2 elements = { 1, 4 }.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that ToString() trip me up.

Comment: The answer by Patrik Svensson should be the accepted answer. This link does not provide an answer...and it is just a link anyway.

Answer (score 14):

```
int[] indexes = myCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>().ToArray()
```

Comment: Actually I access them like that:  myCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices[0].